# GCP Cloud Function Authentication Without Auth Token For End Users?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I want to be able to give a few end users a simple URL they can authenticate against using their GCP credentials to run a Cloud Function. I don't want them to be generating authentication tokens, etc.

Reading the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#developers), it seems simple enough:

1. I create a OAuth 2.0 client ID,
2. select the application type (in this instance, a web application),
3. set the name and
4. select the restrictions.

I'm given a Client ID and Client Secret after doing so, but it's not particularly clear where these are meant to be used from the documentation.

It says to simply re-deploy the Function and it should work as expected, yet when I go to test the function (as Project Owner and being explicitly given the Cloud Functions Invoker role), I receive a `403 error` message saying:

`Your client does not have permission to get URL /test-hello from this server.`

I'm only deploying the simple `hello world` function to ensure I understand the concepts correctly, so there shouldn't be any code issues here.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible with this method?

Comment: Do you use the end-user authentication?

Comment: In what way? Like I say: I just want to know if it's possible to provide them with a simple URL which they're then prompted to authenticate to with their Google credentials.

Comment: I meant [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#end-users)

Comment: Edit: Ah, I see I need to include the 'sign in to Google' code, as demonstrated here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/; thanks!

Comment: Yes, exactly! And then use the ID_TOKEN to call the function. It should work!